# How does Android decide which app can first write to the disc?

Tags: android, io

If two Apps want to write data to the disk, how does Android decide which App gets to write its data first?

Is it strictly first-come-first-served?

Is there a way to give an App priority, so that it gets to write its data first?

Comment: Probably not, but you can add a Lock system in both apps to manage this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If two Apps want to write data to the disk, how does Android decide which App get's to write it's data first?

Android does not "decide" anything.

> Is it strictly first-come-first-served?

Yes, insofar as there is no control over write order. Android 1.x/2.x used YAFFS2 as a filesystem, and that had a global process-level lock over disk I/O, so there was a strict FIFO approach to the filesystem. Android 3.0 switched to ext4, the same filesystem used in most Linux machines, and on there, multiple processes can perform I/O simultaneously, within the limits of hardware.

> Is there a way to give an App priority so that it get's to write it's data first?

Not really. App A cannot tell Android "do not let App B write to disk until the year 2037", for example.